# Asp.net MVC 4 Dynamic CheckBox Not Posting Values To Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want list checkboxes for dynamicly. I am listing checkboxes but values not posting to controller.

Property in Model:

```
Public Property PaymentTypes() As IList(Of PayType)
    Get
        Return repRestaurant.GetAllPaymentTypes()
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IList(Of PayType))
        _PaymentTypes = value
    End Set
End Property
```

PayType :

```
    Public Class PayType

    Public Property PayTypeID As Integer
    Public Property PaymentName As String
    Public Property Checked As Boolean = False


End Class
```

View :

```
  @For i As Integer = 0 To Model.PaymentTypes.Count - 1

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m) m.PaymentTypes(i).Checked)

            Next
```

Watch screen after the posted to action :

[image]

Comment: can you check the generated html please?

Comment: [generated html](http://s30.postimg.org/xf1xt4vs1/Ads_z.jpg)

Comment: Your dynamic checkboxes will be posted as a string array, so you will need to add a string[] property to the update model

Comment: how to update PaymentTypes property with checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in paytype property set method. i changed property set and problem fixed